# Property Editor Exception with Joda LocalDate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, editor, jodatime

I'm using Joda and Local Date. I created a custom property editor, it receives the correct value from the view, like `"23-05-2017"` but when I try to parse it I obtain:

```
LocalDatePropertyEditor - Error Conversione DateTime
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "23-05-2017" is malformed at "-05-2017"
```

This is my custom editor:

```
public class LocalDatePropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{
    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocalDatePropertyEditor.class);   

    public LocalDatePropertyEditor(Locale locale, MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( messageSource.getMessage("dateTime_pattern", new Object[]{}, locale));
    }

    public String getAsText() {
        LocalDate value = ( LocalDate ) getValue();
        return value != null ? new LocalDate( value ).toString( formatter ) : "";
    }

    public void setAsText( String text ) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        LocalDate val;
        if (!text.isEmpty()){
            try{
                val = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").parseLocalDate(text);

                setValue(val);
            }catch(Exception e){

                logger.error("Errore Conversione DateTime",e);
                setValue(null);
            }
        }else{
            setValue(null);
        }
    }
}
```

and inside the controller I registered it:

```
@InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(final ServletRequestDataBinder binder, final Locale locale) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDate.class, new LocalDatePropertyEditor(locale, messageSource));
    }
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the pattern you are using to parse the `LocalDate`.

Instead of:

```
val = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").parseLocalDate(text);
```

Use this:

```
val = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy").parseLocalDate(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

If format of your date is `23-05-2017`, then you use wrong pattern. You should use `dd-MM-yyyy` instead of `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it, just use following in controller, 
you can change pattern 'dd-MM-yyyy', if want to.

```
@InitBinder
private void dateBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

    PropertyEditor editor = new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            if (!text.trim().isEmpty())
                super.setValue(LocalDate.parse(text.trim(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")));
        }
        @Override
        public String getAsText() {
            if (super.getValue() == null)
                return null;
            LocalDate value = (LocalDate) super.getValue();
            return value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        }
    };
    binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDate.class, editor);
}
```